# Right way to add labels to d3-geomap

Tags: d3.js, topojson, choropleth

I try to add labels to map done with [d3-geomap](https://d3-geomap.github.io/), but can't make it work.

The choropleth map itself gets painted correctly, but adding the labels doesn't work out right. The labels show up on the wrong position.

After painting the map I loaded again the topojson file again and then add text blocks like that:

```
d3.json("https://d3-geomap.github.io/d3-geomap/topojson/countries/ESP.json").then(function(es) {

      let path = d3.geoPath().projection(d3.geoMercator());
      svg.select("svg").append("g")
          .selectAll("labels")
          .data(topojson.feature(es, es.objects.units).features)
          .enter().append("text")
          .attr("class", "place-label")
          .attr("x", function(d) { return path.centroid(d)[0]; })
          .attr("y", function(d) { return path.centroid(d)[1]; })
          .attr("text-anchor","middle")
          .text(function(d) { return d.properties.name; });
    });
```

The problem here is that I can't figure out the correct position of the labels. I also tried to apply the same transform as to the polygons, but then have all the same y position.

Here is the example on [bl.ocks](https://bl.ocks.org/geraldo/43f35ef2bcae926aa32757c6be20c531).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made some changes to your code and published it [in this gist](https://gist.github.com/yaph/5714d48fee1f1996415f73549e1b15c6). When testing it locally, the map displayed like the image below. At this size, labels don't work well, but if you resize the map and/or show fewer labels it should be okay.

[image: rendered map]

Some info on the changes. Whenever you want to draw something on top of a map with d3-geomap, it should go in the `postUpdate` function. This way the map is already rendered and its SVG elements, the geo data and the path object are accessible via the map object you created. No need to load the Topojson file a second time. The function passed to `postUpdate` looks like follows:

```
function drawLabels() {
    map.svg.append("g").attr('class', 'zoom')
        .selectAll("text")
        .data(topojson.feature(map.geo, map.geo.objects.units).features)
        .enter().append("text")
        .attr("class", "place-label")
        .attr("x", function(d) { return map.path.centroid(d)[0]; })
        .attr("y", function(d) { return map.path.centroid(d)[1]; })
        .attr("text-anchor","middle")
        .text(function(d) { return d.properties.name; })
        .on('click', map.clicked.bind(map));
}
```

[This page of the documentation](https://d3-geomap.github.io/docs/map-properties/) shows the available map attributes and accessor functions. Hope this helps.

Comment: That looks great, thanks. Actually I'm going to draw values as labels, they should git so. Any change to make labels also work with your great zoom function?

Comment: I updated the gist and the sample code adding the `zoom` class and a click handler.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I created another [bl.ocks](https://bl.ocks.org/geraldo/17c047ed1e882088d5e0c6e8526623f5) and now it looks quite acceptable.

Comment: Hi @geraldo thank you for the wonderful work. I am currently struggling to place the labels on world map correctly. For eg USA/Canada labels are way away from the region. Could you give me idea how to do it correctly?

Comment: You have everything in the `drawLabels` function in the last blocks example. Mainly you center the label using `map.path.centroid(d)`, if you don't want to have them in the center you have to play with x and y attributes.